# Attributes as Blocks with dynamic key and value in Terraform

Tags: terraform, cloudflare

I would like to create Terraform module for Cloudflare and I stuck with [cloudflare_zone_settings_override](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cloudflare/cloudflare/latest/docs/resources/zone_settings_override) settings block. I am unable to create it dynamically based on input variable containing map.

Goal is to have input variable settings_override which is gonna have variable number of settings inside. Example:

```
  settings_override = {
    always_use_https = "on"
    ssl              = "flexible"
  }
```

What I would like to achieve is something like this, where I can have variable number of settings on input (*it is module, so it can be variable per environment*) .

```
resource "cloudflare_zone_settings_override" "this" {
  zone_id   = cloudflare_zone.this.id
  for_each  = var.settings_override

  settings {
    always_use_https = "on"
    ssl              = "flexible"
  }
}
```

however I am always receiving the same error:

```
Error: Argument or block definition required

  on main.tf line 72, in resource "cloudflare_zone_settings_override" "this":
  72:     each.key = each.value

An argument or block definition is required here. To set an argument, use
the equals sign "=" to introduce the argument value.
```

Not working code. I have also tried way with `dynamic`, however **settings** block can be only one so I do not think that's the right way to do it...

```
variable "settings_override" {
  description = "Override Cloudflare configuration"
  type        = map(string)
  default     = {}
}

resource "cloudflare_zone_settings_override" "this" {
  zone_id   = cloudflare_zone.this.id
  for_each  = var.settings_override

  settings {
    each.key = each.value
  }
}
```

Is this even possible using Terraform? Or I have to specify all possible options and replace them using for_each?

> Terraform version v1.0.6 
> Cloudflare provider version: 2.10.1

Comment: "block definition is required here" - what is the full message? Where is this "here"? Also its not clear what do you want to achieve. You want to have some default values that you overwrite from parent module?

Comment: Hi @Marcin, thanks for you comment. I have included full error in the post, so it should be more clear now. I want to achieve, since it's override, passing settings block into the module. Once it wich two options, another time with ten. No default values (default values are set by Cloudflare), only values which needs to be overridden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to explicitly provide all options. For example:

```
resource "cloudflare_zone_settings_override" "this" {
  zone_id   = cloudflare_zone.this.id

  settings {
    always_use_https = lookup(var.settings_override, "always_use_https", null)
    ssl = lookup(var.settings_override, "ssl", null)
    mirage = lookup(var.settings_override, "mirage", null)
    # ... and so on
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was something I wanted to avoid, but it seems like there is no other option.

Comment: btw. is this solution equivalent to lookup - `always_online = try(var.settings_override["always_online"], null)` ?

Comment: It helped to solve the issue, however due to some issues with Cloudflare provider, I had to comment out all unused properties - remove this resource from state and keep there only things that are required. Don't know why, but I get "cannot change readonly values".